# Best practices for dealing with images in a web application using Spring Boot and React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I know there are different options when it comes to storing images, such using AWS buckets, Cloud Storage in general, public folders in the application, storing in databases as Base64 etc.. What it is the most reliable and best option to use if you have to deal with multiple images.

Comment: it really depends on your needs, if you want to store large amount of image, I would recommand cloud storage solution like [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage?hl=en) or AWS. If you have few images, you can directly store it into a folder of your server or in your database